# Recyclerview Limite de linhas

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

estou com um problema, tenho um `RecyclerView`, e está trazendo as informações perfeitamente. Ele é básico apenas listas abaixo do outro, só que não está trazendo todos os registros, faço a consulta por outro ambiente e retorna todos os dados.

Percebi que fica faltando sempre algum registro no final, como se tivesse um limite.

Código xml do `RecyclerView`.

```
android:id="@+id/idRecycler"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```

Acima do `RecyclerView` tenho `EditText` e `Button`.

Meu onCreateViewHolder

```
View vista = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista_horarios, viewGroup, false);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        vista.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return new HorariosHolder(vista);
```

Meu onBindViewHolder

```
horariosHolder.txtHorario.setText(listaHorarios.get(i).getHorario().toString());
        horariosHolder.txtLinha.setText(listaHorarios.get(i).getLinha().toString());
        horariosHolder.txtTarifa.setText(listaHorarios.get(i).getTarifa().toString());
```

Meu HorariosHolder

```
TextView txtHorario, txtLinha, txtTarifa;//, txtSaida, txtChegada;

        public HorariosHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtHorario = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHorario);
            txtLinha = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtLinha);
            txtTarifa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTarifa);
        }
```

Fragmento `onCreateView`

```
View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_consultar_horarios, container, false);
recyclerHorarios = (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.idRecycler);
        recyclerHorarios.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
        recyclerHorarios.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: Bom dia! Poste o restante do código (adapter, local onde adiciona os itens ao adapter e cria a recyclerview, o código do layout)

Comment: Me desculpe se não fui claro o suficiente. Edite sua pergunta e inclua lá o código. [Clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/375114/edit) para isso

Comment: Olá, consegui resolver, coloquei essa linha no `RecycleView`.

`app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`